# UPDATE with condition

Tags: sql

I have a SELECT statement which return correct values, but I need to make price less by 25% for all fruits and vegetables. Is it possible to select columns I need and then update them.

```
SELECT product.id, product.product_title_id, product.manufacturer_id, product.price, product.comment 
   FROM product
   JOIN product_title ON product.product_title_id = product_title.id
   JOIN product_category ON product_title.product_category_id = product_category.id
   WHERE product_category.name = 'fruits' OR product_category.name = 'vegetables'
```

Comment: You can just add your multiplier in your `SELECT` list, like `product.price * 0.75`.

Comment: But I need not to display with some changes, but make UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

not completely sure without seeing your data, but you could just use what @halfer suggested in an update statement.

```
UPDATE product
SET price = price*0.75

FROM product
JOIN product_title ON product.product_title_id = product_title.id
JOIN product_category ON product_title.product_category_id = product_category.id
WHERE product_category.name = 'fruits' OR product_category.name = 'vegetables'
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6270662cf67d2127cbce236da63682be)